# How can I convert the following assembly code to pseudo code?

Tags: disassembly, x86, decompilation, c

I got the following disassembly code in IDA pro. I really find it hard to convert it into pseudo code.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 14h
mov dword ptr [ebp-14h], 1
mov dword ptr [ebp-10h], 2
mov dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], 3
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0

loc_401022:
 cmp dword ptr [ebp-4], 3
 jge loc_40103D
 mov eax, [ebp-4]
 mov ecx, [ebp+eax*4-14h]
 mov [ebp-8], ecx
 mov edx, [ebp-4]
 add edx, 1
 mov [ebp-4], edx
 jmp loc_401022

loc_40103D:
 xor eax, eax
 mov esp, ebp
 pop ebp
 ret
```

Comment: Please, format your code (CTRL+K).

Comment: "I really find it hard to convert it into pseudo code" - what are you finding hard about it?

Comment: As @wisk mentioned you can convert all those `[ebp-XX]` into stack variables. Either `Ctrl+K` or individually by clicking on the instruction parameter and pressing `K` to make a local variable. You can also name them, e.g. `[ebp-4]` could be `idx`. The code will become much clearer.

Comment: @zxxc I was talking about the code in the post before it was edited. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll only add you some comments to make it easier for you to solve it:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

// Reserve space for local variables on the stack - in your case is array
sub esp, 14h
// Initialize local variables - local array
mov dword ptr [ebp-14h], 1
mov dword ptr [ebp-10h], 2
mov dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], 3
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0

// We have a loop here
loc_401022:
 cmp dword ptr [ebp-4], 3     // Index variable
 jge loc_40103D               // Exit from the loop

// Think what is happening here :-)
 mov eax, [ebp-4]
 mov ecx, [ebp+eax*4-14h]
 mov [ebp-8], ecx

// Update the index variable
 mov edx, [ebp-4]
 add edx, 1
 mov [ebp-4], edx
 jmp loc_401022

// Function ending
loc_40103D:
 xor eax, eax
 mov esp, ebp
 pop ebp
 ret
```